# Simplifying radical expressions if possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does one go through the process of attempting to simplify $\sqrt[3]{150}$?

What I did was divide the radicand by 2,3,4 etc. and hope that I find a perfect cube.

Is there a better way to simplify this expression?

Comment: Is the fastest way to divide the radicand by perfect cubes (8, 27, 64, 125) and hope that I find a whole number?

Comment: Well, what about doing a prime factorisation?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 thanks, math makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to factor $150$ into primes and see if any prime has an exponent at least $3$.  We have $150=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$ so there is no factor you can pull out.